# NSSplitView programmatically Change Size

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I was wondering if there's a way you can programatically change the position of the splitter.

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried resizing the subviews inside the panes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the position of the divider using [`setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSplitView/setPosition%3aofDividerAtIndex%3a)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick reply...

And for interest sake, I found this on the way (might be useful for others)

Thanks...And for interest sake, I found this on the way (might be useful for others) which I found here: [on Github](https://github.com/malcommac/NSSplitView-Animatable/blob/master/NSSplitView+DMAdditions/NSSplitView+DMAdditions.m)

```c
- (CGFloat)positionOfDividerAtIndex:(NSInteger)dividerIndex {

    while (dividerIndex >= 0 && [self isSubviewCollapsed:[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:dividerIndex]])
        dividerIndex--;

    if (dividerIndex < 0)
        return 0.0f;

    NSRect priorViewFrame = [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:dividerIndex] frame];

    return [self isVertical] ? NSMaxX(priorViewFrame) : NSMaxY(priorViewFrame);
}
```

I personally used `-(float)`, so use whichever "floats" your boat :D